# Calling luabind derived member as a coroutine

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

The luabind documentation says to call a Lua-derived virtual member from C++, you create a wrapper class derived from `luabind::wrap_base` and call the function like so:

```
class BaseWrapper : public Base, public luabind::wrap_base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo()
        {
            call<void>("foo");
        }
};
```

So far so good - I have this much working.

But how do I implement `BaseWrapper::foo()` to call the overridden `foo` (on the Lua side) as a coroutine (using `resume_function`) instead of calling it directly with `call`?

This is how it's done with non-member functions:

```
luabind::object func = luabind::globals(L)["bar"];
luabind::resume_function<void>(func);
```

I think what I need to know is how to get `func` for `foo` (as implemented by the Lua-derived class), and then my existing `resume_function` logic should work as-is.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not looking for the C++ routine to run as a coroutine itself. I understand this is impossible. In the actual architecture of my program, it will be passing func off to my existing coroutine scheduler and returning immediately.

Comment: You lost me with the part where it seems like the C++ class BaseWrapper derives from a Lua base class, yet the C++ foo() calls the Lua foo().  Can you clarify?  Maybe if the two foos are not really the same you could rename one of them, or add the Lua base class code, or something.

Comment: They should be named the same, because Lua's is overriding C++'s in a derived class (in this case, `foo` is a pure virtual method of `Base`). Anyway, I've figured it out, and will write up the answer momentarily.

Comment: Ugh, I don't have enough reputation to post my answer yet, it seems. Will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out the answer to this problem. It seems that the simplest solution is to pass `self` from Lua when you construct the object and then look up the function from its table:

On the C++ side:

```
BaseWrapper::BaseWrapper(luabind::object self) : _self(self)
{ }

virtual void BaseWrapper::foo()
{
  luabind::object func = _self["foo"];

  /* now put func in coroutine scheduler queue and when appropriate call: 

     luabind::resume_function<void>(func, _self);
  */
}
```

And in Lua:

```
class 'Derived' (Base)
  function Derived:__init()
    Base.__init(self, self)     -- the second self is param to BaseWrapper()
  end

  function Derived:foo()
    -- here is the target function
  end
end
```

Comment: You should be able to walk the lua stack to determine that self? (That said, I'm not sure what these classes are...  Lua doesn't normally have classes)